# Remove an XenApp/StoreFront Application Shortcut from a Thin Client

Tags: thin-client, xenapp, xendesktop, wyse

I would like to know if someone know an easy fix for that:

**Symptom**

I publish XenDesktop's desktop, and I'am migrating an XenApp farm from version 6 to 7.9. (my xendesktop's farm is already migrated to 7.9)

Now on the Wyse, the user see their application and their desktop. (and I don't want that!)

That way it's seen:

[image]

**Problem**

In the printscreen from the wyse direct, we just see Microsoft Word, but I have over 50 published app, I can't fill the desktop with all of them.

Via the DHCP I push the website to connect (/desktopappliance), and on the Web Interface I just list the Desktop Delivery Controller, not any XenApp ressource.

Now with 7.9 and StoreFront, my Web Interface seem broke to only list desktop ressourceg., anyone know a quick tip to remove all **Apps** and to list only Desktop for my **/desktopappliance** website ?

Right now I'am checking all config inside /desktopappliance, like WebInterface.conf and web.config, but nothing seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the posperity, I found a answer to my problem;

On your FTP */Wyse/wnos/ .ini*

Add that new option into ***SessionConfig=ICA***

**OnDesktop=Desktops**

The final line in my case look like that;

> SessionConfig=ICA mapdisksunderz=yes Smartcards=no 
>   Ondesktop=Desktops